# NullPointerException em JasperFillManager.fillReport

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

Renho uma aplicação e quando chega nessa linha

```
JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(in, null, conn);
```

O sistema retorna a seguinte mensagem de erro :

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.jaspersoft.studio.debug.TraceGovernor.setup(TraceGovernor.java:111)
 at com.jaspersoft.studio.debug.TraceGovernor.initMaps(TraceGovernor.java:118)
 at com.jaspersoft.studio.debug.TraceGovernor.beforeReportInit(TraceGovernor.java:162)
 at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDatasetScriptlet.beforeReportInit(JRFillDatasetScriptlet.java:78)
 at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRAbstractScriptlet.callBeforeReportInit(JRAbstractScriptlet.java:176)
 at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportStart(JRVerticalFiller.java:243)
 at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:122)
 at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:551)
 at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseReportFiller.fill(BaseReportFiller.java:393)
 at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:91)
 at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:456)
 at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:417)
 at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:838)
 at Relatorios.RelEmpresas.btnEntrarActionPerformed(RelEmpresas.java:405)
 at Relatorios.RelEmpresas.access$500(RelEmpresas.java:37)
 at Relatorios.RelEmpresas$6.actionPerformed(RelEmpresas.java:224)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
 at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
 at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
 at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
 at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
 at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
 at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
 at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
 at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
 at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
 at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
 at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
 at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
 at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
 at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
 at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
 at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
 at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:184)
 at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:229)
 at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:227)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:227)
 at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1084)
 at java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1671)
 at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Component.java:1623)
 at java.awt.Window.setVisible(Window.java:1014)
 at java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Dialog.java:1005)
 at Relatorios.RelEmpresas$13.run(RelEmpresas.java:552)
 at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Aqui vai o meu código :

```
Connection conn = ConectaBD.getConnection() ;
HashMap parametros = new HashMap(); //Será utilizado quando for usar parametros para o relatório. 

try {                           
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream("C:\\ProjetoSesmt\\FtiSesmt\\src\\Relatorios\\reportEmp.jasper");                                
    JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(in, null, conn);                                

    JasperViewer jv = new JasperViewer(jp, false);                
    jv.setVisible(true);
    jv.toFront(); 

} catch (JRException ex) {
    //Logger.getLogger(RelEmpresas.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Erro ao chamar o relatório!\nErro: "+ ex);
} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(RelEmpresas.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Erro ao chamar o relatório!\nErro: "+ ex);
}
```

Comment: Parece um bug. Olhando [o codigo fonte do Jasper Studio](http://code.jaspersoft.com/svn/repos/jaspersoftstudio/tags/6_3_1_final/com.jaspersoft.studio/src/com/jaspersoft/studio/debug/TraceGovernor.java) ele está tentando ler uma propriedade de uma configuração que pode não ter sido inicializada: `Boolean b = jrConfig.getPropertyBoolean(key, false);`. Eu encontrei [uma entrada no SOen](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38511505/664577) dizendo que ele "resolveu" o problema removendo o `TraceGovernorExtensionsRegistryFactory` do `jasperreports_extension.properties` dentro de um jar. Puro workaround...